# magento 2 full page cache

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, varnish, memcache

does magento suppose to create separate cache for each visitor? 
I configured varnish using magento guide, but each new visitor gets cacheble page only on seocond load.

Comment: share your vcl file. we need to see its logic.

Comment: the file was generated by magento: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35535699/varnish.vcl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, according to Alan Kent's [excellent article](http://alankent.me/2014/12/09/magento-2-caching-overview/) Varnish is only used to cache *public* content. Private content is handled different and basically ends up being cached locally in the user's browser. To quote the linked article:

> What Magento 2 does instead is to fetch a (typically) 95% complete page and then rely on JavaScript and AJAX to inject the last 5% of user specific content onto the page.

It sounds like something is wrong in your configuration, in my tests so far I haven't seen behavior as you describe (only getting a cacheable page on second load).